# как распарсить данные формы из js

Tags: javascript, dom

**Упрощенный пример проблемы:**

```
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="product[gallery][images][1chtf6pqkio7wvup61][file]" value="/_/2/_2.jpg.tmp">
  <input type="hidden" name="product[gallery][images][1chtf6pqkio7wvup61][name]" value="test.jpg">
  <input type="hidden" name="product[name]" value="prod">
</div>
```

Таких input-ов много, в name расписан многомерный массив. Ранее это отсылалось в php.

**Задача**

Посредством js получить из этого дива многомерный массив (или обьект) с сохранением структуры описанной в name. Тоесть нужно получить такойже массив как в php но в js

На данный момент вижу решение только в прохождении по всему дереву этого элемента, а потом регуляркой парсить name и рекурсивно создавать массив. Но может есть какие то простые инструменты и методы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не вижу проще вашего решения:

```js
function createFormObject(node) {
    var obj = {};
    var children = node.children;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        if(!child.name) continue;
        var propertyChain = child.name.replace(/\]/g,"").split("[");
        var chain = obj, j;
        for(j = 0; j < propertyChain.length - 1; j++) {
            var property = propertyChain[j];
            chain[property] = chain[property] || {};
            chain = chain[property];
        }
        chain[propertyChain[j]] = child.value;
    }
    return obj;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(createFormObject(document.getElementById("test"))));
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="product[gallery][images][1chtf6pqkio7wvup61][file]" value="/_/2/_2.jpg.tmp"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="product[gallery][images][1chtf6pqkio7wvup61][name]" value="test.jpg"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="product[name]" value="prod"/>
</div>
```